# Linking two html forms in backend and fetch data from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I've to insert two html forms in a webpage, One is a dropdown which consists of the names of the attributes of a phone directory, and a text field where we can enter any value of the corresponding attribute(selected in dropdown) and generate the search results from the database. I am done with the front end and I've created a database as well. I really don't have any idea about that.
Can someone help me with linking both the forms and generating results in tabular format?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, I would strongly recommend you read [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), SO doesn't provide / find tutorials for you, much less do the coding for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You will require PHP or another similar *server-side* scripting language to do that.

Please have a look at [this tutorial on W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Languages required: HTML, PHP, SQL.

Comment: Thanks..!! But I've gone through that, I couldn't find how to link two forms internally.